# Area appears as querystring in .netcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

In asp.net core, I defined the area for the `Admin` module and I made the necessary configuration for url mapping as follows. However, the area appears as a querystring on the link. What exactly could be the reason for this? Even though I tried many different patterns in `MapControllerRoute`, the problem did not go away.

Startup.cs

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "areas", pattern: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Areas/Admin/Controllers/BaseController.cs

```
[Area("Admin")]
public abstract class BaseController<T> : Controller where T : BaseController<T>
```

Areas/Admin/Controllers/HomeController.cs

```
[Area("Admin")]
public class HomeController : Controller{}
```

Areas/Admin/Controllers/CompanyController.cs

```
[Area("Admin")]
public class CompanyController : BaseController<CompanyController>
```

Areas/Admin/_Layout.cshtml

```
<a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Company" asp-action="CompanyIndex">Company</a>
```

And as I mentioned, the area appears as a querystring.

```
http://localhost:49256/Company/CompanyIndex?area=Admin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the route

```
 endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "areas", pattern: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

above

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

like:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
     endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "areas", pattern: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
     endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
   
});
```

Otherwise it will match the first path.

Comment: Right! Thank so much @Yinqiu